# ionic 2 push on ios won't reach the device

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic2, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to push notification with postman and Firebase, but I'm having some problems with the iOS notifications.
I guess the Firebase configurations are right, since I had an invalid apns credentials error before and now I got a succesfull.

So, this is my postman:

[image]

And this is the code I'm using

```
initPushNotification() { 
if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
  console.warn("Push notifications not initialized. Cordova is not available - Run in physical device");
  return;
}
const options: PushOptions = {
  android: {
    senderID: "883847118563" 
  },
  ios: {
    senderID: "883847118563"
  },
  windows: {}
};
const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log("device token ->", data.registrationId);
  localStorage.setItem("pushToken", data.registrationId);

  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({ 
              title: 'device token',
              subTitle: data.registrationId,
              buttons: ['OK']
            });
            alert.present();

});

pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log('message', data.message);
  if (data.additionalData.foreground) {
    let confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({ 
      title: 'New Notification',
      message: data.message,
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Ignore',
        role: 'cancel'
      }, {
        text: 'View',
        handler: () => {
        //  this.nav.push(DetailsPage, {message: data.message});
        }
      }]
    });
    confirmAlert.present();
  } else {
  //  this.nav.push(DetailsPage, {message: data.message})
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({ // o que fazer quando clica na app
              title: 'clicked on',
              subTitle: "you clicked on the notification!",
              buttons: ['OK']
            });
            alert.present();
    console.log("Push notification clicked");
  }
});

pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
}
```

And this are my cloud settings:

```
const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
 'core': {
  'app_id': 'bde818c3' // ID da app @https://apps.ionic.io/apps/
  },
 'push': {
  'sender_id': '883847118563',
  'pluginConfig': {
  'ios': {
    'badge': true,
    'sound': true
  },
  'android': {
    'iconColor': '#ff0000'
    }
   }
  }
};
```

Note that some code here is just for testing.
So, my Android receive the notification without the problem but the ipad can't receive it. I have give permitions to the app to get notifications on the ios settings...
Any advice?
Thank you for the help.

Comment: I have the same problem right now. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @dvdpzzt it was the apple certificates, if I remember right I followed this guide, it was a bit confusing.. I followed some guide but I dont remember which one, sorry.

Comment: I finally managed to make it works by removing the .p8 key from firebase and added the developernt and production certificates .p12.

Comment: @dvdpzzt glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented a way to received the notifications?

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{


// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)



    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
}


}
```